# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'bind' - backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am getting the following error : `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'bind'` with backbone.

```
var UpdatingPostView = PostView.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.render = _.bind(this.render, this);

        this.model.bind('change:title', this.render);
    }
});
```

Here is the calling function(s).

```
posts.fetch().complete(function() {

    var postCollectionView = new PostCollectionView({
        collection: posts,
        el: $('.posts')[0]
    });

    postCollectionView.render();

});
```

Here is PostCollectionView

```
var PostCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (post) {
        var that = this;
        this._postViews = [];

        this.collection.each(function() {
            that._postViews.push( new UpdatingPostView({
                model: post,
                tagName: 'div'
            })); 
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        var that = this;
        //Clear out this element
        $(this.el).empty();

        //Render each view and append to parent element
        _(this.postViews).each(function (dv) {
            $(that.el).append(dv.render().el);
        })     
    }
```

Comment: Just do some debugging and figure out what `this.model` is... We can't do that part for you. Start with `debugger` and see where that takes you.

Comment: `$(this.el)` should be [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el), you can [`_(x).each(fn, this)`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) to avoid a lot of the `var that = this` noise, `el: '.posts'` should work just fine, and [`this.model.on('change:title', this.render, this)`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) or [`this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:title', this.render)`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) would obviate the need for binding `render`.

Answer (score 1):

What is `post` here?

```
initialize: function (post) {
    var that = this;
    this._postViews = [];

    this.collection.each(function() {
        that._postViews.push( new UpdatingPostView({
            model: post,
```

When you instantiated this earlier, you did so with...

```
var postCollectionView = new PostCollectionView({
    collection: posts,
```

I'm not an expert on Backbone, but I'm pretty certain it isn't wired up to pass a singular post to the initializer of a collection which is passed an array of posts.

I think your initializer should probably look something like this:

```
initialize: function () {
    var that = this;
    this._postViews = [];

    this.collection.each(function(post) { // <<<<< function(post) is important
        that._postViews.push( new UpdatingPostView({
            model: post,
```

Comment: spot on, not sure how i missed that! Cheers!